# How To See A Database On Heroku

Tags: python, database, heroku

How do I see the database for my heroku web app?

I just want to verify if users are being registered, properly, etc.

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy Python, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to it using something like PGAdmin, look at the output of `heroku config` for your application to get your database URL which you can breakup to use in GUI tools.